# How to find the parent using the hierarchyid data type

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, hierarchical-data

This code here does not work when I try to find a single parent node

```
declare @val hierarchyid
select @val = dbo.GetHierarchyIDbyID(30)

--get the parent
select * from NodeHierarchy
where @val.GetAncestor(NodeHierarchyID) = 1
```

How would you go about finding the parent?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming the name of the field containing the hierarchy ID is "hid", you could do the following:

```
DECLARE @val HIERARCHYID  
SELECT @val = dbo.GetHierarchyIDbyID(30)  
SELECT * FROM NodeHierarchy WHERE hid = @val.GetAncestor(1)
```